# What does 2>&1 in this command mean?

Tags: command-line, io-redirection, wget

I understand that this command attempts to write to nowhere or a null device but what does `2>&1` mean here?

```
wget -q -O - http://yourwebsite.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Gilles found this one which seems even more like a dup: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37660/order-of-redirections

Answer (score 127, accepted):

`2` refers to the second file descriptor of the process, i.e. `stderr`.

`>` means redirection.

`&1` means the target of the redirection should be the same location as the first file descriptor, i.e. `stdout`.

So `> /dev/null 2>&1` first redirects `stdout` to `/dev/null` and then redirects `stderr` there as well.  This effectively silences all output (regular or error) from the `wget` command.

::edit:: [Here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) is an excellent quick reference for you.

Comment: Thanks. When run in a shared hosting cron job which typically sends an email of the output to an admin, would the > /dev/null 2>&1 prevent this from happening do you think? Also do spaces surrounding '>' matter?

Comment: Yes, the complete silencing trick is standard practice to make sure that absolutely no output exists to trigger email from a cron job.  (Note, however, that the hosting provider may have done all sorts of strange things to your cron environment to make it send some sort of email regardless of your efforts.) ::edit:: And no, spaces around the lone `>` do not matter, but spaces within the `2>&1` probably do matter (I can't recall).

Comment: It might also be worth noting that the same semantics are often achieved with the idiom `&>/dev/null`