# Running lsf jobs in personal ubuntu pc

Tags: linux, ubuntu, platform-lsf

I have somewhat maybe little bit strange question running my jobs in my ubuntu laptop instead of running them hpc clusters.

The reason I want to to that is now I have 6 core 12 threads. I used to run my jobs on hpc cluster of my previous university.

What I was doing,

1) connecting to hpc cluster and go to where the execution file is which is `wave_func.out`

submitting the jobs to lsf

3) `bsub -q linux22 -i ./w1.in -o ./w1.out ./wave_func.out`

Then the if there is available thread in 'redhat7_211' my simulation starts.

My question is, How can I perform these simulation on my personal ubuntu OS pc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following:

- `wave_func.out` is an executable binary. As opposed to, say, a data file.
- Its installed on your ubuntu pc, in the current working directory.
- The input file `w1.in` is in the current directory.
- The software's license allows you to run it on your pc.
- all its dependencies are available on your ubuntu pc.
- your account on the ubuntu pc uses bash as the shell

Then the following command should work.

```
./wave_func.out < ./w1.in > ./w1.out 2>&1
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your assumptions all correct. I finally executed the file. One question though what does `2>&1` do?

Comment: `2>&1` redirects the standard error stream to the same file used for the standard output stream. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99263/what-does-21-in-this-command-mean) for more details.

Comment: thank you very much for the information. It helped a lot understanding things better. If I may, I would like to ask some questions to about how execute multiple `w1.in` files in parallel. Let's say I want to execute multiple files such as `w1.in, w2.in and w3.in`, what would be the best way to achieve this ? On top of that, are these jobs will be running parallel such that my 6 core 12 thread machine dedicate 3 core for this ?